# wp_editor is changing the path of images

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am developing my own plugin but some where I got stucked..as I am trying to add wp_editor() to put a custom section of editor, all working good but there is path problem like if I insert a image through text editor and then image inserted properly and absolute path is there but if I click on the visual tab to see how does it looks and come again on the text editor tab then it losts the full path and it shows something like this .../wp-content/xyz/image.jpeg instead of http://domain.com/wp-content/....

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use wp_editor($meta, 'content1');

In that the $meta is the array of custom post and content is the id of that filed.